# Getting "Trying to get property 'subtotal' of non-object" when using findOrFail

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I've got the following piece of code in a service:

```
public function add(array $data) : Order
    {
        // retrieve item data
        $item       = MenuItem::findOrFail($data[OrderItem::ORDER_ITEM_ITEM_ID]);
        $quantity   = $data[OrderItem::ORDER_ITEM_QUANTITY];
        $order_no   = $data[Order::ORDER_NO] ?? null;
        $session_id = $data[Order::ORDER_SESSION_ID];

        $order = $order_no ? Order::findOrFail($order_no) : $this->createOrder([Order::ORDER_SESSION_ID => $session_id]);

        $order_item = $this->order_item->createOrderItem($order->order_no, $item, $quantity);

        // update order total
        $order->subtotal += $order_item->subtotal;
        $order->total    += $order_item->subtotal;
        $order->update();

        return $order;
    }
```

When running a test I'm getting:

> Getting "Trying to get property 'subtotal' of non-object"

The retrieved object is not empty, otherwise it'd have failed. But neither subtotal nor total belong to the object. If I print the object I get the other fields except for these two. They both are in my `$fillable` array and I defined a `->default(0);` in my migration.

What's going on?

**EDIT**

PHP Unit Output Below:

```
PHPUnit 8.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

array:5 [
  "message" => "Trying to get property 'subtotal' of non-object"
  "exception" => "ErrorException"
  "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/app/Services/OrderService.php"
  "line" => 110
  "trace" => array:33 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/app/Services/OrderService.php"
      "line" => 110
      "function" => "handleError"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    1 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/app/Http/Controllers/API/OrderController.php"
      "line" => 57
      "function" => "add"
      "class" => "App\Services\OrderService"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "function" => "add"
      "class" => "App\Http\Controllers\API\OrderController"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    3 => array:3 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php"
      "line" => 54
      "function" => "call_user_func_array"
    ]
    4 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php"
      "line" => 45
      "function" => "callAction"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Controller"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    5 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php"
      "line" => 219
      "function" => "dispatch"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    6 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php"
      "line" => 176
      "function" => "runController"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Route"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    7 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 681
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Route"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    8 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 130
      "function" => "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    9 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 105
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    10 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 683
      "function" => "then"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    11 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 658
      "function" => "runRouteWithinStack"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    12 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 624
      "function" => "runRoute"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    13 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 613
      "function" => "dispatchToRoute"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    14 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      "line" => 177
      "function" => "dispatch"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    15 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 130
      "function" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    16 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 105
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    17 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      "line" => 152
      "function" => "then"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    18 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      "line" => 117
      "function" => "sendRequestThroughRouter"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    19 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php"
      "line" => 434
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    20 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php"
      "line" => 406
      "function" => "call"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    21 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/tests/Feature/OrdersTest.php"
      "line" => 428
      "function" => "json"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    22 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      "line" => 1408
      "function" => "when_adding_the_same_item_twice_to_an_empty_order_then_only_one_order_item_is_created_but_its_quantity_increases"
      "class" => "Tests\Feature\OrdersTest"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    23 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      "line" => 1028
      "function" => "runTest"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    24 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php"
      "line" => 691
      "function" => "runBare"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    25 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      "line" => 756
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    26 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php"
      "line" => 597
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    27 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php"
      "line" => 597
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    28 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php"
      "line" => 597
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    29 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php"
      "line" => 621
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    30 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php"
      "line" => 200
      "function" => "doRun"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    31 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php"
      "line" => 159
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\TextUI\Command"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    32 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/bigweld/Sites/restaurantbe/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit"
      "line" => 61
      "function" => "main"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\TextUI\Command"
      "type" => "::"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: What does `createOrderItem` actually return? Given this is a test, are you mocking it out and returning a known result?

Comment: `createOrderItem` returns an object of type `OrderItem`. The error message is not coming from `OrderItem` but from `Order` when I try to access `$order->subtotal` and `$order->total`. `$this->createOrder()` returns an obj of type `Order` as well as `Order::findOrFail()`, and an object is actually returned, but without `subtotal` nor `total` properties

Comment: Ok, I missed the `+=` on that line, but the subtotal is on both objects in that line, so I wasn't sure which was being referred to. Can you confirmed that both items are objects?

Comment: I believe I've found the issue. The error output was pointing me to classes related to Order. After you mentioned `createOrderItem` I check my service for `OrderItem` and saw the following in `createOrderItem`:
```
$order_item->quantity += $qty;
        $order_item->subtotal += ($item->price * $qty);
        return $order_item->update();
```
Apparently the issue is in the return statement. I modified to do the update a line above and simply return `$order_item` and it seems to be working. Thanks for forcing me to check there

Comment: @Jason I just added the error output, as you can see it never complained about `createOrderItem` in `OrderItemService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our conversation in the comments, one of the issues you have in your function, and consequently causing a problem in your test, is a dependency where the outcome cannot be guaranteed each time. That is, your call to another service in your `add` function is not *guaranteed* to provide a specific output.

Think of your test like this.

- I start with an order with zero items, and a zero subtotal
- I want to add an item to that order
- I want to end with an order with one item, and a ten dollar subtotal

In this test, you don't care *how* the order item is created, you just care that it *is* created, with a specific value, so that when it is added to your order, the end result is what you expect.

In this case, what you want is for `$this->order_item` to be a mocked object, and then you can mock the call to `createOrderItem` to return a known order object. It's a bit difficult to show you a complete solution as it may involve some architectural changes, but your test would be something like:

```
public function it_adds_an_item_to_an_order()
{
  $orderItem = Mock(OrderItem::class); // Use whatever mocking lib is available
  $orderitem->shouldReceive('createOrderItem').andReturn(new OrderItem([$subtotal=>10.00]));
  $orderService = new OrderService($orderItem);

  $order = $orderService->add($data);

  $this->assertNotNull($order);
  $this->assertEquals(10.00, $order->subtotal);
}
```

Hope this assists you in a way forward.

Comment: I like where this conversation is going. I appreciate the tip as I'm relatively new in the world of unit testing and this would be one of my first projects using TDD. I'm not very familiar with mocking stuff, my current tests are more like integration tests. I have already a test for simple order creation (adding one item to an order) this specific one was to add the same item to the same order. In order to use `order_item` service in my `Order` service I'm injecting it via constructor along with the `Order` model and that's something that is not very convincing for me